# Need assistance with coding assignment! How to stop my if else statement so it only runs once

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I need help with how to make my code's if else statement to only run once and I was wondering if I followed all the instructions that were asked for this assignment. Also, i may have some errors or placement issues. I am a beginner javascript user as I never used the program before this. The instructions are below as followed:

- Run an if/else statement to see if age is less than 60, then display alerts depending on the result
- Push a third question to the questions array
- Push the corresponding array of answers to the answers array
- Add if and else if statements to the score-checking to increment the score at different levels for each answer: 3 points, 2 points, or 1 point depending on the user’s choice. These should be implemented for all three questions. Try to use a for loop to cycle through all the questions and answers, and consider using the index in the array for the scoring system.
  -Add `<br>Score:` plus the user’s score to their paragraph (`id='myParagraph'`) by using `document.getElementById` to change the innerHTML
- Add an additional prompt asking the user to calculate the results of a basic math question
- Increment the user’s score by 5 if their answer to the math question is equal to the results of the same math question as an expression: make sure the equation is part of your if statement.

Code below:

```js
var question = ['What is your quest?', 'What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow?', 'What planet\'s moon can more liquid water than all of Earth\'s oceans?'];
var score = 0;
var answers = [
  ['To seek the grail', 'I don\'t know that', 'To be in Monty Python'],
  ['African or European?', '92', '24'],
  ['Europa', 'Titan', 'Pandora']
];
console.log(answers);
console.log(answers[1][0]);
var name = prompt('What is your name?');
//alert('A message;);
document.getElementById('myParagraph').innerHTML = 'Hello ' + name + '!';
document.getElementById('myScore').innerHTML = 'You scored ' + score + 'points!';
console.log(typeof name);
var age = prompt('How old are you?');
console.log(typeof age);
age = Number(age);
console.log(typeof age);
if (age < 60) {
  alert(age);
}
for (var i = 0; i <= age; i++) {
  document.write(i);
  document.write(' ');
}

var math = prompt('What is 16+2-1*3=?');
console.log(typeof math);
math = Number(math);
if (math === 15) {
  alert(math);
} else {
  alert('You are incorrect');
}
for (var j = 0; j <= math; i + 5) {
  document.write(j);
  document.write(' ');
}
var guess = prompt(question[0] + '\n\u2022 ' + answers[0][0] + '\n\u2022 ' + answers[0][1] + '\n\u2022 ' + answers[0][2]);
if (guess === answers[0][0]) {
  score += 3;
  console.log(score + ' ' + 'points earned!');

} else if (guess === answers[0][1]) {
  score += 2;
  console.log(score + ' ' + 'points earned!');

} else if (guess === answers[0][2]) {
  score += 1;
  console.log(score + ' ' + 'points earned!');
}

var guess = prompt(question[1] + '\n\u2022 ' + answers[1][0] + '\n\u2022 ' + answers[1][1] + '\n\u2022 ' + answers[1][2]);
if (guess === answers[1][0]) {
  score += 1;
  console.log(score + ' ' + 'points earned!');

} else if (guess === answers[1][1]) {
  score += 2;
  console.log(score + ' ' + 'points earned!');

} else if (guess === answers[1][2]) {
  score += 3;
  console.log(score + ' ' + 'points earned!');
}

var guess = prompt(question[2] + '\n\u2022 ' + answers[2][0] + '\n\u2022 ' + answers[2][1] + '\n\u2022 ' + answers[2][2]);
if (guess === answers[2][0]) {
  score += 3;
  console.log(score + ' ' + 'points earned!');

} else if (guess === answers[2][1]) {
  score += 2;
  console.log(score + ' ' + 'points earned!');

} else if (guess === answers[2][2]) {
  score += 1;
  console.log(score + ' ' + 'points earned!');
}
```

```html
<br id="myScore">
<p id="myParagraph">A paragraph!</p>
</br>
```

Comment: You begin with `if(...` continue with `else if(...` and finish with `else(...`

Comment: I tried that, but the code wasn't working I want to ask 3 questions and have 3 answers with the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite loop here:

```
for (var j = 0; j <= math; i + 5) {
  document.write(j);
  document.write(' ');
}
```

Since you never modify `j`, `j <= math` is always true, so the loop never ends.

I don't see any reason for this loop in the first place. The problem specification says to add 5 to the user's score if they get the math question right. So you should do:

```
if (math === 15) {
  alert(math);
  score += 5; // Add 5 to the user's score
} else {
  alert('You are incorrect');
}
```